# Free group with relations

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I understand that $\langle a\vert a^2\rangle$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

My question is $\langle a,b,c\vert a^2b^2c^2\rangle$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus\mathbb{Z}_2$?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, how did you show the first one? Remember that there are no other relations than the one shown, so in particular, no elements are assumed to commute unless forced to do so by the relations.

Comment: Do you mean $\langle a,b,c\mid a^2,b^2,c^2\rangle$ ?

Comment: @lhf I mean without the commas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope! We can collapse $\langle a, b, c|a^2b^2c^2\rangle \to \langle a, b, c|a^2b^2c^2, c=ab=ba=e\rangle=\langle a, b|ab=ba=e\rangle=\mathbb{Z}$. Clearly this is surjective. Thus we have a surjection onto $\mathbb{Z}$, so the group is not even finite! Note since we factored through the abelization, even commutativity is not a problem, this is just a problem of insufficient relations.

Edit:
As for the collapsing part, it is acutally pretty straightforward. If you have a free group on three letters, $F_3$, and denote the normal subgroup generated by $\{a^2b^2c^2\}=I$ and $\{a^2b^2c^2, [a,b], c, ab\}=J$, then the group you are talking about is $F_3/I$ by definition. Now I am talking about $F_3/J$. Now we have $I\subseteq J$, which means that $J/I$ is normal subgroup of $F_3/J$, so we have a map $F_3/J\to (F_3/I)/(J/I)=F_3/J$ by Noether's Third theorem. This actually is a lot more general! If we talking about some $n$-letters, for some cardinal, with relations $R\subseteq Q$, then the exact same aurguments creates a map $\langle n| R\rangle \to \langle n| Q\rangle $.

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain a bit on the collapsing part?

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, regarding to $\langle a|a^2=1\rangle\cong\mathbb{Z_2}$, $$\langle a,b,c|a^2=b^2=c^2=1, [a,b]=[a,c]=[b,c]=1\rangle\cong\mathbb{Z_2}\times\mathbb{Z_2}\times\mathbb{Z_2}$$

Comment: Thanks, is it still true if we omit the commutator part, I.e [a,b]=...=1

Comment: I think as we use disjoint genetaing sets, I mean ${a,b,c}$ so we should write a new version of relation. This relation indicates that $a$ commutes with $b$ and $c$ (and this is true for $b$ and $c$). I remmember this from my course.

Comment: @yoyostein: No. If we omit the commutor part then the group ends up with elements like $abababa$ which you can't do anything with. $\langle a,b,c|a^2=b^2=c^2=1\rangle$ is still an infinite group.